# I can't see my JPanel and its components in the JApplet

Tags: java, swing

I want to put a `JPanel` in a `JApplet`, the problem is that I can't see it :( I've overridden the `paintComponent` of my `JPanel` in order to have a background image, but I can't see anything. When I remove the `paintComponenet` method that I had overriden, and set a color to the background of this panel, it seems that `JPanel` fills the `JApplet` and still no component is visible :-S  I've tried different layouts. I also put my panel in the center of another panel which fills my `JApplet` but nothing changed, and still no component and no background image is visible :(

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Main extends JApplet implements Runnable{

private JTextArea display;
private Thread outputThread;
JPanel boardPanel;

private ClientViewManager view;

@Override
public void init() {

    try {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't successfully complete");
    }

}

private void createGUI() {

    display = new JTextArea(4, 30);
    display.setEditable(false);
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(display), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setFocusable(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setName("CE Tanks");
    setSize(600, 600);
    setLocation(100, 100);

    boardPanel = new JPanel();
    boardPanel.setLayout(null);
    boardPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(128, 255, 255));
    getContentPane().add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public void start() {
    outputThread = new Thread(this);
    outputThread.start();
}

public void run() {
                view = new ClientViewManager();
                boardPanel.add(view);
                boardPanel.repaint();
                repaint();
    }
}


 class ClientViewManager extends JPanel {
private int rows=8;
private int columns=8;

public ClientViewManager() {
    super(null);

    JLabel lb= new JLabel("lb.jpg");
    lb.setLocation(10, 10);
    lb.setSize(50, 50);
    lb.setOpaque(false);
    lb.setVisible(true);

    this.add(lb);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon("ground.jpg").getImage(), 0, 0, columns * 50,
            rows * 50, this);
}

}
```

The code above can be compiled. I cant even add `Keylistener` to neither my `JPanel` nor to my `JApplet`. I used `java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher` and in `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)` I printed something in console but, it was printed 3 times.  :(

Comment: little bunny foo foo is right.

Comment: @Maryam:  *"Plzzzzzzzzz HELP"* Please 1) Stop using nonsense spelling such as "Plzzzzzzzzz" 2) Stop SHOUTING at us. 3) Ask a question.

Answer (score 5):

> I've overridden the paintComponent of my JPanel inorder to have a background image,

But you didn't add the custom component to your applet:

```
//boardPanel = new JPanel();
boardPanel = new ClientViewManager();
```

Also:

1. get rid of setVisible(). This is not required for any of the controls in your program. By default all components except top level Container (Jframe, JDialog etc) are already visible. In the case of JApplet, you don't need to make it visible as this is part of the process of displaying an  applet.
2. get rid of setSize() and setLocation() you can't control the position of the applet this way.
3. Don't read the image file in the paintComponent() method. This is not efficient as this method is invoked whenever Swing determines the component needs to be repainted.
4. JLabels are opaque by default so there is not need to invoke the setOpaque method.
5. When doing custom painting you should also override the getPreferredSize() method of the component to return the proper size of the custom painting so layout managers can use this information. It works in this case because you added the panel to the CENTER of the BorderLayout. Try adding the panel to the NORTH to see what happens.

Edit:

Now I see where you are adding the ClientViewManager. I'm not sure why you are trying to do this with a Thread but once again there are several problems.

1. When you add/remove components from a visble GUI then the basic code is:

   panel.add(...);
   panel.revalidate();
   panel.repaint();
2. However this still won't work because you are using a null layout and the size of the panel is 0. Use a proper layout manager and implement the getPreferredSize() method as suggest above and the component will be displayed properly.

Comment: Thank u for responding me, but I cant get what u mean by "you didn't add the custom component to your applet" :"> [i put it in run method ] BTW, i guess i did what u said, and i overrode the getPreferredSize() but sry my JApplet is still empty :( i guess the problem is with the image because i see the label with a text inside it , but no background image for the panel :(

Comment: Read my edit. Your code doesn't make any sense. In the init() method you add an empty panel. The simple solution I gave you was to add ClientViewManager at this time. For some reason in the start() method you create a Thread to add the ClientViewManager. This is very confusing.

Comment: The image is loaded fine when I run the code using the Appletviewer. In general when using applets you would not use an ImageIcon to load an image. I suggest you look at the Swing tutorial on "How to Make Applets" (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for an example of how to load images.

Comment: you're right. my code seems confusing, but this code is part of a bigger class. would u mind telling me what should i do to put a keylistener in my applet? (it didn't work 4 me) i used KeyEventDispatcher, that works, but the problem is that everything happens 3 times :-/

Comment: Each KeyStroke generates 3 events, "pressed", "typed", "released", so you need to check the event code. KeyEvents go to the component with focus. So you need to add a panel to the applet. Make the panel focusable and and the KeyLIstener to the panel. If you need more help then you need to create another SSCCE that deals only with that issue and create another question since each thread should only have a single question. Then you can accept an answer for this thread and move on.

Answer (score -4):

I recommend you to use the GUI Builder of Netbeans to build a GUI like that, and then compare the generated code to your code. Netbeans results really useful to help you create swing code.

Comment: -1, that is a comment not an answer to the question. Even if it was an answer I would down vote it because you should never compare you code to generated code because code generation is never efficient.

Comment: Ok, that´s a comment, I agree, but for solving that problem that is the more straighforward way I can think of, instead of changing code here and there.

Comment: i haven't worked with Netbeans and i guess it takes some time for me to learn it. Unfortunately, I don't have enough time for learning it. I should send my assignment next week. But, Thank u for your advice, ;)

Comment: @jaime: `"for solving that problem that is the more straightforward way I can think of, instead of changing code here and there"` and thereby gaining no understanding of how Swing works. This *solution* will not help the original poster learn anything.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels you are misunderstanding me, first you create the GUI with netbeans, then you check the generated code and you can take the generated copy as reference

Comment: @jaime: please compare the NetBeans generated code to some of the code posts here by Swing experts for instance by camickr, Andrew Thompson, or trashgod, then tell me *honestly* that a newbie is better off learning *and understanding* Swing by emulating the generated code vs. the guru's code. The fact is the generated code was never meant to be emulated by humans nor should it be used as a learning tool.

Comment: I was just talking in my experience, say I wanted to get an icon over a JLabel, and the advices found here or anywhere wasn't working for me (maybe because my lack of familiary with Java/Swing), so I went to the Netbeans GUI editor, drag a label, select an icon, ran the project and seems to be working, went to generated code, and there it was a clear and good starting point to get my problem solved. Simple, without the need to think too much, or even try to understand the loading mechanism or anything else, and maybe because I just don't care.